# Nonresolvable Parent POM in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm trying to use the m2e Maven connector in Eclipse.

In Eclipse I set a run configuration with a goal of 'install' and profile of 'run'.

But I get an error that is something like the following:

```
Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find com.jonney-parent:pom:3 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 13 -> [Help 2] [ERROR]
```

I tried a right-click on the project and Maven->Update Project... in Eclipse, but the error persisted.

I finally went to the command line and ran:

```
mvn install -U
```

That caused Maven to start downloading the right dependencies.

But what am I doing wrong in Eclipse that I couldn't get it to do anything there?

Comment: Did you check your eclipse >preferences >maven > user settings ? is it pointing to same settings.xml that your command line refers to ? For that matter also check if your Maven_HOME value is same as the eclipse > preferences > maven > installation

Comment: You're right.  In Eclipse it was set to use the embedded version of Maven.